# Supervisord overriding environmental variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, restart, supervisord, application-restart

I have an application (deployed in docker container) managed via supervisord

My `supervisord.conf` looks like:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
loglevel=INFO

[program:anjay]
priority=1
#USE SOME_CLI for different run configurations
command=/some/binary %(ENV_SOME_CLI)s
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=false
stopsignal=INT
user=root
```

I want to be able to restart `/some/binary` with different arguments (driven by `SOME_CLI` env variable)
Starting the application for the first time works perfectly, arguments are expanded. E.g.:

```
export SOME_CLI=A
/some/binary A
```

Then I want to `export` new `SOME_CLI=B` and I expect after restart:

```
export SOME_CLI=B
/some/binary B
```

Unfortunately there still is

```
/some/binary A
```

Is it possible to restart configured application with different arguments that way?
If no, how to achieve such functionality?

Remark: I know that my application is deployed in container and I could just restart the container with different arguments. It just doesn't seem to be the right thing to do (restart whole container just to change some arguments).

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: *First thing*: do **NOT** run supervisor inside the container. Containers are meant to run one application and one application only. It's not a VM, its a container.

Environment variables are read once, and are not updated unless the process restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Add the environment variable directly on your conf file in the [program] section, such as:

```
[program:anjay]
environment=ENV_SOME_CLI=your_value
```

Apply changes by telling supervisord there's a change in that file with `supervisorctl update`.

Comment: Try again not calling the binary directly but running a shell script where the actual command and the reference to the environment variable are present.